# publishing notification from a thread running continuously in a service

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have a service and in that service i have a thread. The thread has a Runnable. From the runnable i am try to publish notification but i am getting this error.

```
The method setLatestEventInfo(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent) in the type Notification is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){}, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent)
```

If i try to publish from outside the thread, everything works fine. 
My application continuously gets a response from the server. When there is updated data from the server and the app is not running a new notification is created. To avoid running on the main thread, i created a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing `this` inside a `Runnable` does not refer to the instance of `Context` (your `Service` or `Activity`) but to the `Runnable` instance.

Try the following:

```
final Context context = this;
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        setLatestInfo(context, charsequence1, charsequence2, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way to reference the enclosing instance via `this` within the `Runnable` is to use the class name : `MyService.this`. That way you don't have to bother using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Context you defined is the problem. you should have the context of an activity or an application.